# Writing a code for the 1st time - Cannot understand why I get an error

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have tried to automate the goal seek function on my excel file. Looked at a code on youtube and tried to use it. It works perfectly till I add the last few names created to the range. I have checked the names and they exist with no typos.

As soon as I add the following "TWOtargetvalue, TWOsetcell, TWOchangecell" to the below formula it give me a Run-time error '1004'range of object _worksheet failed

```
Set inputcells = Range("INFTargetvalue, INFsetcell, INFchangecell, FXTargetvalue, FXsetcell, FXchangecell, MFOBtargetvalue, MFOBsetcell, MFOBchangecell," & _
    "CORtargetvalue, CORsetcell, CORchangecell, OPTtargetvalue, OPTsetcell, OPTchangecell, ONEtargetvalue, ONEsetcell, ONEchangecell," & _
    "TWOtargetvalue, TWOsetcell, TWOchangecell")
```

This is the formula I am using the range for

```
Range(Range("TWOsetcell").Value).goalseek Goal:=Range("TWOtargetvalue"), _ ChangingCell:=Range(Range("TWOchangecell").Value)
```

Can someone please help me! Any advice would be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: There's a 255-character limit for the range address. Use `Union`.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your reply. I don't know how to use the union function. May I ask where is it to be used and how?

Comment: @Gavin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union